# installing app in the Android tablet

Tags: android, sqlite, tablet

I have an android app which uses sqllite, i have the apk files built in 2.2 sdk. It runs smoothly on the emulator, but when I installed it on the Samsung Galaxy Tab (Android tablet) it gets installed but wont run. It gives me error "my_app_name(my_package) have stopped unexpectedly. Please try again "..I don't know why this happens..

please help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using DDMS to see what the error is? It should report the line of Java it crashed on and give you an indication as to the problem..

Comment: the app is not crashing while running on the emulator...the problem is while it is on the device

Comment: Understandable, but you can still run DDMS when it's running on the device. Plug the tablet in via USB, make sure you've enabled debugging in the settings panel. The device should appear in the DDMS window - click on the device and you'll have access to the live device log.